# What does the iPhone developer program give me over and above simple registration as an iPhone developer?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

Simply put; what does my $99 get me, that I can't already get for free?

OK, OK, sounds like a dumb question, but the Apple site is not clear to me.

My hunch is that you get the ability to submit apps to the app store for your 99, but you could get everything else for free, but it's not clear to me hence the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After paying the $99 the main benefits are shown below:

- Install your developed apps on your device without Jailbreaking
- Submit and distribute paid and free apps to the Apple App Store
- Access to coupon codes to distribute your paid app to reviewers (neat feature)
- Distribute an internal app using ad-hoc distribution for up to 100 devices
- Free additional marketing if your application is popular (generally not available to everyone)

Those are the main benefits, I don't think I have forgotten any of the key benefits.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot actually run your program on a any iPhone/iPod touch, including the one you own, without paying the $99.

Comment: this answer still stands in december 2012. you would expect that when you pay the price for an iPhone 5, you can AT LEAST test your own app on it...

Answer (score 2):

For $99 you can run your app on your actual device and you can sell your app.