# iphone development

Tags: iphone, ipad

I heard that any software be published to Apple store should have a apple developer license for $99/year, is this true?

Comment: Not really a programming question per se, but I have to imagine that it took you longer to create this question than it would have taken to go to the apple dev site and confirm this for yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the iPhone developer program give me over and above simple registration as an iPhone developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465330/what-does-the-iphone-developer-program-give-me-over-and-above-simple-registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apple Developer Connection](http://developer.apple.com/) plan for iOS is 99$/year (or 79€ in Europe I guess) and it gives you the advantages that rcapote wrote, BUT [signing for free](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) does not allow you to submit your app on the App store. There is also another way to deploy apps on the iDevices, you have to jailbreak them and use software like [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/) and Installous to test on them.

Maybe the most important task in your app development cycle, testing on a real device, can be done only paying the fee or for free if you are in a University developer program so consider it carefully (however you could alway buy a license in the future and start now for free and get confidence with the SDK, IDE etc)

**EDIT** The answer was a bit messy

Comment: you ssaid "signing for free allows you to submit your app for free on the App store.", is this contradict with what rcapote ssaid?

Comment: I am the one who wrote the answer badly, I meant you could always use the free tool and SDK to deploy later on Cydia. I'd better update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to pay the $99/year licensing fee to submit your App to the App Store, as well as being able to test your app on your device. Along with those two features, you also gain access to Apple's developer forums and beta access to new OS versions.

Comment: Is there any other way to copy application to my own iphone?